# How to implement Image slider with indicator in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to implement image slider in android similar to [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) . But I need to do this without any third party dependencies . Is there any sample for implementing the same using View pager , or anything else. I need the exact slider style , with dot indicator

[image]

Comment: Hi can I ask u if u find a solution on this question? Would be amazing if u can help me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to implement the same.

Step1: 
create two circle images, one for on and other for off.

Step2: 
Create three blank fragments for displaying the image. you can create as many as you want.

Step3: 
Create a footer.xml to place the circle indicator.

Step4: 
Create a fragment_main.xml to place the viewpager.

Step5: 
Create an adapter class.

Please check this http://javaant.com/viewpager-with-circle-indicator-in-android/#.Vx3_gJN96Ht
to download the complete code